# Loop that skips the values it already done

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, loops

With this code i mange to take take all the different possibilities, add them together and put in the data in my arrays. The problem is that i get some duplicated data which i want to skip. Example:

> First:  name1, name2, total points of this two and total price for this two.
>   Then: name2,  name1, total points of this two and total price for this two. **Which is the exact same result but in diffrent order.**

Data is a list of 3 colums with about 50 lines ( name , price and point )

```
price = 0
points = 0

l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []
l4 = []

for i in range(0,18):
    for i2 in range(0,18):
        points = data['Points'][i]+data['Points'][i2]
        price = data['Price'][i]+data['Price'][i2]

        if price < 10 and i != i2:
            l1.append(points)
            l2.append(price)
            l3.append(data['Name'][i])
            l4.append(data['Name'][i2])

            print points , price, data['Name'][i], data['Name'][i2]
            print '_____'
            print ''
```

Question: How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to this to avoid going over every combination twice:

```
for i in range(0,18):
    for i2 in range(0,i):
        ...
```

I would delay the `points = data['Points'][i]+data['Points'][i2]` calculation to after the `if` case to save a little time.

And you don't need to initialize variables like `price = 0, points = 0` since they are redefined on every iteration anyway. Python is a dynamic langue so variable declarations are generally unnecessary.

Comment: Pleas upvote as well if you are happy with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary instead of a bunch of lists to make sure you only have one entry for each combination of names.

```
results = {}
for i in range(0,18):
    for i2 in range(0,18):
        if i == i2:
            continue

        # Your dictionary key will be a tuple of the names. 
        #Use min and max to ensure the same pair of names always makes the same key
        key = (min(data['Name'][i], data['Name'][i2]), \
               max(data['Name'][i], data['Name'][i2]))
        if key in results:
            continue

        points = data['Points'][i]+data['Points'][i2]
        price = data['Price'][i]+data['Price'][i2]

        if price < 10:
            results[key] = (points, price)

            print points , price, data['Name'][i], data['Name'][i2]
            print '_____'
            print ''
```

Comment: is there any easy way to insert that tuple in a dataframe so it would make 3 columns(name, point, price) and then a new line for each entry?